# Am I adding unnecessary data to a junction table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a junction table, say for People and Locations

### PersonLocations

```
PersonId | LocationId
---------------------
    1          3
    2          5
```

Now, Locations can belong to each other i.e. one location can sit inside another, which can sit inside another etc., so I have this defined by the `Location` table referencing itself:

### Locations

```
LocationId | ArbitraryName | ParentLocationId
--------------------------------------------
    1          a country           null
    2          region a              1
    3          village 1             2
    4          village 2             2
    5          region b              1
```

So you can see `village 1` and `village 2` belong to `region a`, which in turn belongs to `a country`

Now, I want it to be known that if person `1` visited Location `3` (`village 1`) as shown in the first table, they also visited Location `2` and `1` - which can be inferred by the `Location` table self-referencing.

But what I've done is written rules (triggers) so that if an entry occurs on the `PersonLocations` table it automatically inserts the `ParentLocationId` (which recursively works until ParentLocationId is null)

so inserting

```
PersonId | LocationId
---------------------
    1          3
```

actually results in

```
PersonId | LocationId
---------------------
    1          3
    1          2
    1          1
```

And vice versa if I remove.

What I really want to know is - **is this safe?** It makes my queries and views much easier but am I missing something that is later going to bite me in the backside? I feel like as long as those triggers are in place it would be fine, although its taking up more space - the payoff justifies it? But at the same time I also feel like I might be violating some principle I don't know about...

Comment: I wouldn't dare to do that.

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: sql-server and / or MySql

Comment: While this probably 'works' - it is a misuse of triggers and could cause serious problems once you get large amounts of data. I would rethink this design

Comment: So basically, I don't want to use the triggers and I should always infer the relationship by joining across the location table with the locationParentId

Comment: Ok well I know what my next question on stack overflow will be - how can I recursively get all the parent locations in one query! :D

Comment: A recursive cte will the the answer to that question.

Comment: It violates normalization, which is a pretty basic principle of database design. Consider what happens when you discover that a location has been mis-classified in terms of it's parent location. In a properly normalized database, you need to update this in *one* place.

Comment: Yeah I had come across this idea while looking elsewhere, definitely made me realise how terrible the idea was!